# What is the difference between a plain WPF app and one that can run on Microsoft Surface?

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

Is there anything I need to add to my WPF application, so it can run on Microsoft Surface? Are there any samples with source code available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional SDK for Surface.
Take a look at the learning page:
http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/Pages/Technical/Learn.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know open-source projects where the surface is targeted?

Comment: No, I don't. Are you specifically into Surface or multi-touch tables? There are other options out there :)

Comment: I am speaking specifically about Microsoft Surface. Are you referring to the iPad? :)

Comment: No, I though about open source one[1] or do-it-yourself-one[2] ;)
[1] http://labs.nortd.com/cubit/
[2] http://marcinignac.com/blog/2008/05/02/multitouch-making-of/